# PHP for Looping MySql id

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am Using Below Code to First Fetch all 'id' from MySql table.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "**";
$password = "**";
$dbname = "**";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$slug = $_GET["category"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = '1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$dealid = $row["dealid"];

}} else {}
$conn->close();
?>
```

`$dealid` should return with all id's but it is returning with only 1.

Now below code is to show data with those id's:-

```
<?php 
$num_rec_per_page=52;
mysql_connect('localhost','**','**');
mysql_select_db('**');
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = $dealid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page";

$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {
?>
<?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/dealbox.php' ); ?>

<?php 
}; 
?>
```

But its only showing 1 data because returning id is only 1. I am not able to understand what the issue is. Any help is appreciable and will gift if someone help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend all Id's are set into one array and return that array,

eg:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) 
{
  $dealid[]= $row['id']; //array creation
}
```

and

```
return ($dealid);
```